# Can not delete a leaf from binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, nodes

I have made a `delete_node()` function of a leaf from a binary search tree BST. Here is the behavior of `delete_node()` function:

1. If the binary search tree was empty, it will inform you that the it is empty.
2. Else if, that leaf has no child, so no further delegation is required. So,           the pointer that points to that leaf is deleted then make it points to null. But the program unfortunately crashed.
   Here is the `delete_node()` function:

   ```
   void  BinarySearchTree :: delete_node(float deleted_key)
   {
     Node* deleted_node_address = return_node_address(deleted_key);

     if(root == NULL) cout<<"The tree is empty, No thing to delete\n";

     else if(deleted_node_address->left_ptr==NULL  &&  deleted_node_address->right_ptr==NULL)
     {
       cout<<"The element has no children, No linking required\n";
       delete deleted_node_address;
       deleted_node_address = NULL;
     }
   }
   ```

Here is the `return_node_address` function:

```
Node* BinarySearchTree  ::return_node_address(float req_key,Node *traverse_ptr)
{
    if(traverse_ptr==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"There is no data to return its addres";
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(traverse_ptr->key  ==  req_key)
    {
        return traverse_ptr;
    }
    else if(req_key  <  traverse_ptr->key  && traverse_ptr->left_ptr != NULL)
    {
        return_node_address(req_key, traverse_ptr->left_ptr );
    }
    else if(req_key  >  traverse_ptr->key  && traverse_ptr->right_ptr!= NULL)
    {
        return_node_address(req_key, traverse_ptr->right_ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The Key You Entred Is Not Found in The Tree";
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: Time to fire up your program with the debugger and step through line by line.

Comment: Get it working then. Usually it does.

Comment: Ok i will try, but does any logic in the above code is wrong?

Comment: Why down voting? i want to know to improve my questions

Comment: you never check if `deleted_node_address` is non-null, so that's a good candidate

Comment: Why close votes? Just because the problem is 'too elementary' for SO geeks...?

Comment: Too elementary, so i should not ask about it !?

Comment: @Ahmed You source code seems inconsistent: the `return_node_address` is defined with two parameters, `float` and `Node*`, and you invoke it with just one. Are you sure you present the actual source, which you compile and run...?

Comment: Why close votes? It appears to me that the most likely cause is the lack of a [mcve]. This typically demonstrates little effort spent debugging the problem yourself, and this offends people for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment

```
deleted_node_address=NULL;
```

clears the `deleted_node_address` variable, which is local to the `BinarySearchTree :: delete_node(float deleted_key)` function, but it does **not** clear the pointer to the deleted node from its parent node.

As a result you made your tree invalid: it remained with some `left_ptr` or some `right_ptr` being not-NULL but pointing to a non-object. Hence a possible crash on the next attempt to access the pointed unused memory.

Additionally, you call `return_node_address()` function to search a node to delete **before** you test for `root==NULL`. Are you sure that `return_node_address` method is NULL-root-proof...?

Comment: You mean that i should make the pointer which is pointing to the deleted node from its parent to be pointing to null? am i right?

Comment: @Ahmed That's right. When you remove the child node, its parent does no longer have that child. And 'having no left child' or 'having no right child' is precisely `left_ptr` or `right_pttr` being `NULL`, respectively.

Comment: @Ahmed Possibly you might google for 'delete a node from BST' and study some example implementations. When you get familiar with the problem and possible solutions, browse again through your code and find out which part is missing in it.